# Laravel count amount where the value of a key is true in multidemensional array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array that looks like this when dd'd out :)

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Comment {#253 ▼
    #guarded: []
    #table: "comments"
    +timestamps: false
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    #attributes: array:7 [▶]
    #original: array:7 [▼
      "id" => "1"
      "on_projects" => "2"
      "from_user" => "19"
      "body" => "hi"
      "unread" => "1"
      "created_at" => "2016-06-13 23:54:39"
      "updated_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ]
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #fillable: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  }
  1 => Comment {#269 ▶}
]
```

Now my goal is to count the amount of where the unread key is true.

This is what I've tried but doesn't seem to be working.

```
$unreads = $comments->where('unread', 1);
dd(count($unreads));
```

I get this error:

> Call to a member function where() on array

Anyone can help me out here?

Many thanks in advance!

### EDIT

```
$uid = Auth::user()->id;
$projects = User::find($uid)->projects;
       
//comments
if (!empty($projects)) {
  foreach ($projects as $project) {              
     $comments_collection[] = $project->comments;
  }
}

if (!empty($comments_collection)) {
     $comments = array_collapse($comments_collection);
     $unreads = collect($comments)->where('unread', 1)->count();
     dd($unreads);
}
```

This gives me 0 it should give me 2 since I have 2 comments with unread 1

Comment: It occurs because your `$comments` variable not type of object, it's array.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add where does this `$comments` variable comes from?

Answer (score 4):

After you've retrieved the data you can collect, filter and count using Illuminate\Collection.

```
collect($comments)->where('unread', 1)->count();
```

That said, if your goal is to simply count the data and do nothing else with it, you could achieve this using Eloquent as presumably you've already used a similar query to get the data in the first place.

```
Comments::where('unread', 1)->count();
```

---

Amends based on OP edit.

```
$projects = Project::with(['comments'])
    ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->get();

$count = $projects->sum(function ($project) {
    return $project->comments->where('unread', 1)->count();
});

dd($count);
```

---

Having thought a bit more about it, as you just want a count (it seems), you can add a relation and an accessor to your Project model.

```
public function commentsCountUnread() {
  return $this->hasOne(Comment::class)
    ->selectRaw('project_id, count(*) as aggregate')
    ->where('unread', 1)
    ->groupBy('project_id');
}

public function getCommentsCountUnreadAttribute()
{
  if (! $this->relationLoaded('commentsCountUnread')) {
    $this->load('commentsCountUnread');
  }

  $related = $this->getRelation('commentsCountUnread');

  return ($related) ? (int) $related->aggregate : 0;
}
```

Then you could do something like

```
$posts = Project::with('commentsCountUnread')->get();

$count = $projects->sum(function($project) {
  return $project->commentsCountUnread;
});

dd($count);
```

Comment: It's a bit complicated to use Eloquent because I get all the projects from the logged in user and get the comments from all the projects check out edited OP.

Comment: I'll give a try as soon as I understand what's happening in your code :)

Comment: I get this error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'comments.project_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select on_projects, count(*) as aggregate from `comments` where `unread` = 1 and `comments`.`project_id` in (2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8) group by `on_projects`)` even though I changed project_id to on_projects as it is in my database

Comment: Because of the `hasOne` relation it makes assumptions about the columns you have. You need to set the column as the second parameter of `hasOne`

Comment: I added the parameter and it seems to be working, only problem I always get 2 as result. I need to get the amount of records where unread=1 from the projects of the logged in user. Does it makes sense what I am trying to say? Here's how my comments table looks like: http://puu.sh/pss9Y/21f4059f6c.png

Comment: That's what the `->where('unread', 1)` on the relation does. It works as expected for me. Only difference seems such that I used the default column names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114653/discussion-between-cruzito-and-ben-swinburne).

Comment: And it works on some pages and on other pages I get error undefined variable soooo weird. I have no idea what is going on lol. It cant be that hard to query the records where unread=1 from the projects owned by the logged in user and then count this query? Or am I missing something?